# Python: Kivy: How to align a label itself and text box?

Tags: python, alignment, kivy, kivy-language

I've tried multiple pieces of code from here, but they all seem to align the text within the label or text box. I want to align the text box and the label vertically and horizontally. I am a beginner at kivy, so please excuse me if the answer is very obvious.

1. Is there a way to align the label itself and not the text inside?
2. Is there also a way to align the text box itself and not the text inside?

Thanks in advance!

This is my .kv file **firstkivy.kv**

```
#Filename: firskivy.kv

<MyGrid>:
    Label:
        text: "Writing"
        font_size: 80
        bold: True
        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
        size: self.texture_size
        text_size: self.size
        halign: 'center'
        valign:'middle'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0.549, 1, 0.984, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos


    TextInput:
        size_hint: (.2, None)
        height: 100
        width: 360
        multiline: True
        size_hint: (None, None)
        font_size: 30
        halign: 'right'
        pos_hint: (None, None)
        focus: True
```

This is the .py file **firstkivy.py**

```
# setting up and fixing the window size
#to prevent it from being resized
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
Config.set('graphics','width', '360')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '540')

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

# going back to this one...
Window.clearcolor = (0.549, 1, 0.984, 1)

class MyApp(Widget):
    pass

#building the app
class FirstKivy(App, BoxLayout):
    def build(self):

        self.title = 'Arabic Language Learning App'
        return MyApp()

# running the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    FirstKivy().run()
```

**Here is the**
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suPuT.png)

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing your `firstkivy.py` like this:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
Config.set('graphics','width', '360')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '540')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window


class MyApp(BoxLayout):
    pass


class FirstKivy(App):
    title = 'Arabic Language Learning App'
    def build(self):

        return MyApp()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FirstKivy().run
```

And your `firstkivy.kv` like:

```
<MyApp>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: 10
    space_x: self.size[0]/3
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.549, 1, 0.984, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            text: "Writing"
            font_size: 80
            bold: True
            color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .8}
            #size: self.texture_size
            #text_size: self.size
            #halign: 'center'
            #valign:'middle'


        TextInput:
            size_hint: 1, .5
            #height: 100
            #width: 200
            multiline: True
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
            #size_hint: None, None
            #font_size: 30
            #halign: 'right'
            #pos_hint: None, None
            #focus: True
```

Hope it achieves what you want.

Comment: Using `center_x` in the `pos_hint` will align the `Widget` centers. You can use `x` to align `Widgets` left edge, or `right` to align `Widgets` right edge.